# Generating larger random integers - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, random, integer

Trying to assign appropriate value to `x` that would result in random integers between 1 to 60. Any suggestions? I did `randn` but am getting small numbers over and over. Here's the code so far:

```
function s = Q11sub1(x)
    x =                 % <------ Question is what goes here
    if x <= 30      
        s = "small";       
    elseif x > 30 & x <= 50       
        s = "medium";  
    else    
        s = "high";  
    end
end
```

Comment: If you're having a problem with a particular program *show us that program please*. Show us how you are using `randn` and we can help you figure out why it is not doing what you expect.

Comment: I note that your `x > 30` check is redundant. If It were `<= 30` then you already executed the consequence of the `if`.

Comment: @EricLippert, `randn` generates continuous random variates from the standard Normal distribution, e.g. N(mean = 0, std = 1).  That function is entirely wrong for this purpose.

Comment: Yes, and that's all that needs to be said to a student who is beginning to learn MATLAB and its functions. *students* make mistakes i.e. using "randn" instead of "randi". No need for all the passive-aggressive answers full of questions, when a simple "Try randi" will suffice. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `randi`:

`randi(60)`

This will give you a pseudorandom integer between 1 to 60.

Reference: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html

Comment: I've upvoted but wanted to add they will be **uniformly distributed** across the integers between those bounds (known as the [discrete uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution)).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `randn` generates random numbers that follow a standard [Normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), e.g. Normal(mu = 0, std = 1).

As @Banghua Zhao points out, you want the `randi` function and I'll add they will be uniformly distributed across the integers (inclusively) between those integer bounds (known as the [discrete uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution)).
The code `X = randi([a b],N,M)` will generate a NxM matrix of integers uniformly distributed on the interval [a,b] inclusively. A call `randi(Imax)` defaults the lower bound to 1.

See the difference below.

[image: Comparison of randi and randn]

```
N = 500;    % Number of samples
a = 1;      % Lower integer bound
b = 60;     % Upper integer bound

X = randi([a b],N,1);   % Random integers between [a,b]
Y = randn(N,1);

figure, hold on, box on
histogram(X)
histogram(Y)
legend('randi[1,60]','randn','Location','southeast')
xlabel('Result')
ylabel('Observed Frequency')
title({'randi([a b],N,1) vs randn(N,1)';'N = 500'})
```

---

EDIT: At @Max's suggestion, I've added `60*randn`.

[image: Comparison of randi and 60*randn]

```
% MATLAB R2017a
W = 60*randn(N,1);     

figure, hold on, box on
hx = histogram(X,'Normalization','pdf')
hw = histogram(W,'Normalization','pdf')
legend('randi[1,60]','60*randn','Location','southeast')
xlabel('Result')
ylabel('Observed Estimated Density')
title({'randi([a b],N,1) vs 60*randn(N,1)';['N = ' num2str(N)]})
```

Comment: Maybe, the difference between randi and randn would become even more clear, if you multiply randn by 60 and then plot again

Comment: @Max, thanks for the suggestion.  I thought of that but I wasn't clear how the OP was using `randn`.  But your advice is solid and I'll update when I get the chance.  Thanks.